# mac os text shortcuts not working in safari -- el capitan

Tags: macos, text, safari, operating-system, shortcut

I created a couple of keyboard shortcuts to auto-type a few things like the current date and my email address

these aren't text expansions, they're services called by a keyboard shortcut

they work fine in, for example, textEdit, or almost any text box, but not the text boxes in safari

I have run this command in terminal:

defaults write -g WebAutomaticTextReplacementEnabled -bool true

but no luck -- any thoughts? I love my shortcuts!

thanks